# Multiple receivers on a single channel. Who gets the data?

Tags: go, blocking, channel

Unbuffered channels block receivers until data is available on the channel. It's not clear to me how this blocking behaves with multiple receivers on the same channel (say when using goroutines). I am sure they would all block as long as there is no data sent on that channel.
But what happens once I send a single value to that channel? Which receiver/goroutine will get the data and therefore unblock? All of them? The first in line? Random?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A single random (non-deterministic) one will receive it.

See the language [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements):

> Execution of a "select" statement proceeds in several steps:
>
> 1. For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send
>      statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering
>      the "select" statement. The result is a set of channels to receive
>      from or send to, and the corresponding values to send. Any side
>      effects in that evaluation will occur irrespective of which (if any)
>      communication operation is selected to proceed. Expressions on the
>      left-hand side of a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or
>      assignment are not yet evaluated.
> 2. **If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection.**
>      Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen. If there
>      is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at least one
>      of the communications can proceed.
> 3. Unless the selected case is the default case, the respective communication operation is executed.
> 4. If the selected case is a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or an assignment, the left-hand side expressions are
>      evaluated and the received value (or values) are assigned.
> 5. The statement list of the selected case is executed.

Comment: Race condition? Is it safe to do?

Comment: Yeah sure, it's just racy which goroutine gets the element.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "race condition". That term is conventionally defined to indicate unintended behavior due to unsafe concurrent access of a variable. Channels are designed to be safely accessed concurrently, and there is nothing wrong with multiple readers on an unbuffered channel.

Comment: @JimB I know that the term has several uses. If you have a better word feel free to suggest it.

Comment: I think you don't need the term at all, and adding it just confuses the matter. There's nothing inherently "racy" about it, since the internal structure of the channel serializes the receive operations.

Comment: It's a non-deterministic choice, in CSP terminology. That's not the same as a race condition. The latter is accidental and harmful, as JimB said. If you want the choice to be deterministic, you might need to use N channels instead of 1, for your N receiving goroutines.

Comment: @Rick-777 Race conditions are not harmful by default. There are critical and non-critical ones (for which this case is an example). Still, non-deterministic is probably the better term as it confuses less people.

Comment: If it doesn't matter the order something happens in or which routine gets the channel input (ie. having a bunch of worker routines that are all able to process the input) then it is not a race condition.

Comment: I don't think the spec for `select {}` is relevant. I believe the documentation you referenced is talking about what will happen when you have a `select` with `case` statements for multiple channels.

Answer (score 5):

By default the goroutine communication is `synchronous` and `unbuffered`: sends do not complete until there is a receiver to accept the value. There must be a receiver ready to receive data from the channel and then the sender can hand it over directly to the receiver.

So channel send/receive operations block until the other side is ready:

**1.** A send operation on a channel blocks until a receiver is available for the same channel: if there’s no recipient for the value on `ch`, no other value can be put in the channel. And the other way around: no new value can be sent in `ch` when the channel is not empty! So the send operation will wait until `ch` becomes available again.

**2.** A receive operation for a channel blocks until a sender is available for the same channel: if there is no value in the channel, the receiver blocks.

This is illustrated in the below example:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int)
    go pump(ch1) // pump hangs
    fmt.Println(<-ch1) // prints only 0
}

func pump(ch chan int) {
    for i:= 0; ; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }
}
```

Because there is no receiver the goroutine hangs and print only the first number.

To workaround this we need to define a new goroutine which reads from the channel in an infinite loop.

```
func receive(ch chan int) {
    for {
        fmt.Println(<- ch)
    }
}
```

Then in `main()`:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go pump(ch)
    receive(ch)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the program is allowing multiple goroutines to receive on a single channel then the sender is broadcasting. Each receiver should be equally able to process the data. So it does not matter what mechanism the go runtime  uses to decide which of the many goroutine receivers will run Cf. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/247. But only ONE will run for each sent item if the channel is unbuffered.

Answer (score 0):

[There have been some](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/247) [discussion about this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11506)

But what is established in the [Go Memory Model](https://go.dev/ref/mem#tmp_7) is that it will be at most one of them.

> **Each send on a particular channel is matched to a corresponding receive from that channel**, usually in a different goroutine.

That isn't as clear cut as I would like, but later down they give this example of a semaphore implementation

```golang
var limit = make(chan int, 3)

func main() {
    for _, w := range work {
        go func(w func()) {
            limit <- 1
            w()
            // if it were possible for more than one channel to receive
            // from a single send, it would be possible for this to release
            // more than one "lock", making it an invalid semaphore
            // implementation
            <-limit
        }(w)
    }
    select{}
}
```